# Remove background image in crystal report upon print

Tags: printing, crystal-reports

I have this crystal report that I created and has a background image that I imported. When previewing it's okay that the image is visible. But upon printing I want that image not to be printed just the plain text/data is needed to be printed. It is possible to do it?.

I've search in google but the sample is different from my problem.

Thanks. New here. BTW I'm using asp.net c# mvc5, VS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible 'out of the box'.

Using code you can print a different version of the rpt or mess around with suppress conditions...